# How to bind json data to KendoUI Chart

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In the example provided on KendoUI Demo site, it's Chart is binded to the json data of these format:

```
[ { "Booked" : 0,
    "Date" : "/Date(1370620800000)/",
    "FailedAttempts" : 0,
    "Views" : 0
  },
  { "Booked" : 0,
    "Date" : "/Date(1370707200000)/",
    "FailedAttempts" : 0,
    "Views" : 0
  }]
```

but what if the server return in this format:

```
    { "AggregateResults" : null, "Data" : [ { "Booked" : 0,
    "Date" : "/Date(1370620800000)/",
    "FailedAttempts" : 0,
    "Views" : 0
  },
  { "Booked" : 0,
    "Date" : "/Date(1370707200000)/",
    "FailedAttempts" : 0,
    "Views" : 0
  },]
```

}

How do i set the KendoUI Chart to bind to the "Data" node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define in you DataSource definition, define [`shema.data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) as "Data".

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
               ...
            }
        },
        schema : {
            data: "Data"
        }
    },
```